# django-filter, ordering objects of many to many field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I am working on API, written in Django.

I have models similar to:

```
class foodprices(models.Model):
    price_description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=8)

class food(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    price_ids = models.ManyToManyField(foodprices,blank=True)
    #I have multiple prices for single food object
```

In my views:

```
class foodviewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = food.objects.all()
    serializer_class = food_serializer    
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter)
    ordering_fields = ('price_ids__price',)
```

This ordering will work fine if i only have single price for my food object. 
In my case, I want to order my food objects based on the first price_id in my food table. I want to omit all other prices, except first while ordering.

I want some thing like this
`ordering_fields = ('price_ids__price[0]',)`

Is it possible with inbuilt Django filters?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the first price? This would be very straightforward if you were using the minimum, maximum, or average price.